# Поменять с помощью конструкции UPDATE имя и пароль пользователя в самом приложении (WPF)

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server, update

Есть окно авторизации WPF через MSSQL таблицу, при регистрации данные пользователя отправляются в ту же таблицу

```
SqlConnectionsqlconn=newSqlConnection(@"DataSource(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AS Database;Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    public LoginScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Opacity = 0.8;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Registration registration = new Registration();
        registration.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (sqlconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlconn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Connection = sqlconn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"select dbo.[AS].* from [AS Database].dbo.[AS] where Username=@n and Passwordd=@f;";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", txtPass.Password);

            bool count = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
            if (count == true)
            {
                Window1 f = new Window1();
                f.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrected");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }


    }


  }
}
```

Задача узнать ID пользователя который присвоил ему компьютер в таблице и с помощью этого ID произвести конструкцию UPDATE для смены имени и пароля пользователя

Ну или ID не нужен Главная задача поменять с помощью конструкции UPDATE имя и пароль пользователя в самом приложении (WPF)

Comment: Да по-всякому можно. Хотите - можно к ID прицепиться, а можно сделать `Update dbo.Users set pass = 'hash' where login = 'asdf'`

Comment: @AK а вот как мне узнать логин если я ввел его в другой форме, то есть как я запомню какой у меня был логин при входе в приложение, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: это не логично писать логин в одной форме, а потом передавать в другую форму.

Comment: Я не понимаю логику. У вас строка подключения к базе содержит integrated security - зачем вам спрашивать логин и пароль для работы, ведь если вы его спросили в форме и забыли, нигде не сохранив - то значит вы пользуетесь Integrated security и введённым логином не пользуетесь. Зачем тогда менять то, чем не пользуемся? ;) Получается, вы один раз ввели логин/пароль при старте приложения, проверили и даёте делать что угодно. А как же разделение прав по ролям, логинам?

Comment: @AK получается при каждом новом пользователе я должен создавать нового пользователя в MSSQL и давать ему права? Если да, то как это сделать, покажите (код например)?

Comment: @AK ответь пожалуйста